# Cosmos DB - Gremlin - Query performance slow when ordering

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I hope that someone could please help me. I have setup a simple test to test query performance for a basic graph. I have included the code below. Basically what I do is create 30000 vertices and then create 20000 edges on one of the vertices.

```
public async Task<bool> runTests(Models.Person person)
    {
        try
        {
            var gremlinServer = new GremlinServer(_hostname, _port, enableSsl: true,
                                               username: "/dbs/" + _dataBaseId + "/colls/" + _collectionId,
                                               password: _authKey);

            using (var gremlinClient = new GremlinClient(gremlinServer, new GraphSON2Reader(), new GraphSON2Writer(), GremlinClient.GraphSON2MimeType))
            {
                await gremlinClient.SubmitAsync<dynamic>("g.E().drop()");
                await gremlinClient.SubmitAsync<dynamic>("g.V().drop()");

                var counter = 30000;
                while (counter != 0)
                {
                    await gremlinClient.SubmitAsync<dynamic>("g.addV('partition" + counter + "').property('id', 'partition" + counter + "').property('profilePicture', '" + person.ProfilePicture + "').property('name', 'Person " + counter + "').property('partitionKey', 'partition" + counter + "')");
                    counter--;
                }

                var counter = 20000;
                while (counter != 0)
                {
                    int num = counter + 1;
                    var personToLink = "partition" + num;
                    await gremlinClient.SubmitAsync<dynamic>("g.V('partition1').addE('friendsWith').to(g.V('partition" + num + "'))");
                    counter--;
                }

                var searchResults = await gremlinClient.SubmitAsync<dynamic>("g.V().hasId('partition1').out('friendsWith').order().by('name', incr).valueMap('name', 'profilePicture').range(0,2)");

                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

When I run the following query results are returned quickly:

```
 g.V().hasId('partition1').out('friendsWith').valueMap('name', 'profilePicture').range(0,2)
```

However, as soon as I add an order clause the query takes much, much longer. Over a minute to complete:

```
g.V().hasId('partition1').out('friendsWith').order().by('name', incr).valueMap('name', 'profilePicture').range(0,2)
```

Is there a way to index the graph to speed this type of query up?

I have another question as well, I have set the throughput to 5000 RU, however when I run a query that run very quickly I get the following:

[Data Explorer Query Stats Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GKxu.png)

What is this value supposed to represent (RU's?) if so why is it so high?

Also when I try to run a simple query:

```
g.V().hasId('partition1').out('friendsWith').hasId('partition20001')
```

I get "Request rate is large" even though this is such a simple query. Even more concerning is when I increase the throughput to 5000 RU's I do get a result back but its really slow, takes about 5-6 seconds for what should be a really simple query.

Comment: Hi, did you find how to do this faster?